# get selected item on redirected page -- how?

Tags: php, javascript, submit

Our site's UI displays read-only text fields which have mouse-click handlers -- when the user clicks one of the read-only fields, we change its CSS to make the text and background color of that item appear "selected."

If the user clicks a 'show item' button on this same page, the next page needs to 'know' which item was selected on the page that it was redirected from.

PAGE A:  user clicks a read-only field to select it; the selection is highlighted via CSS 
.........and user can click a 'Show Item' button on this page to see the details of the selected item -- we redirect to Page B to show the selected item's details.  The 'Show item' will NOT be a form 'submit' button, just a standard button.

PAGE B: Gets redirected to.  Needs to know what item on Page A was the selected item (using the item's ID or value etc.)

How?  If you are inclined to say 'Ajax' don't bother, I do not have that in my allowed suite of options, nor jquery, those are my marching orders.

The onclick handler is client-side code on Page A.   The redirection is via window.location="page2.php"

I do not see any way that Page A can make Page B aware of the selected item's name or ID or etc. -- it's not a form post, it's all client side code.

Although I might be missing something, pls let me know if I am.  I'm stuck right now.

Reaching for straws, I thought of calling submit() but I don't think I can pass anything that way
that would allow Page B to know which item on Page A was selected, besides the fact that submit()
requires A-Form.submit() and the 'Show Item' button is *not* on a form on Page A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

capture the click event and return the target's id. pass the target's id as a url param on the redirect.

Comment: Hi, thanks, not sure if you noticed, but the redirect is all client-side -- the redirect happens via this code: window.location="page-B.php" and I don't see any way to pass url params with a client-side call like window.location="page-B.php."

Comment: window.location="page-B.php?caller=" + id;

Answer (score 1):

when redirecting just append required information with `#` prefix like this : `window.location="page2.php#1,2,3,4"` and then on the page2 parse those values using JS.

you can access values you have passed by `window.location.hash` in JS

Comment: @j_mcnally also -- wow, I didn't realize it.  Then the params passed that way are in the $_GET array in php and available to page-B.php's code?

Comment: the hash will not be passed to php it is only available in javascript. so it depends how you want to use the param.

Comment: Okay I'll need to use the window.location="page-B.php?caller=" + id  approach because the logic on Page B needs to query the database for lots of stuff about the selected item (hence the need to switch to a different, dedicated page to show it all).  Man, I *REALLY* appreciate learning about the hash # and the GET params technique with window.location -- thank you, and +1's all around.

Answer (score 1):

In your onclick event handler, execute an ajax request to your server that performs something like

```
<?
session_start();
$_SESSION['selectedVariable'] = intval($_GET['foo']);
?>
```

Next page load, your site will know, as it is stored in the session.

Of course, this won't work really well with multiple tabs.

Comment: Thanks Aron, coding protocols are such that jquery, ajax, etc. are not allowed, by decree, but truth be told there have been several places where Ajax was the right answer -- thank you for your suggestion.